# Update dom during synchronous execution

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement an Angular Material progress bar

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="totalAmount !== undefined">
  <mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" [value]="(100 * processedAmount) / totalAmount"></mat-progress-bar>
  <span>{{ processedAmount }} / {{ totalAmount }}</span>
</ng-container>
```

I'm trying to update the progressbar during a synchronous function:

```js
processedAmount?: number;
totalAmount?: number;

doStuff() {
  this.processedAmount = 0;
  this.totalAmount = 100;

  for (let i = 0; i < this.totalAmount; i++) {
    // do some synchronous computation here
    this.processedAmount++; 
  }
}
```

This is a simplified function that I'm invoking. My problem is that the DOM is not updated during the function execution, only after the function finished, the full progressbar is displayed.
How can I update the progressbar during the function execution? I tried wrapping the updates to `processedAmount` and `totalAmount` in a `setTimeout` or NgZone run, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

wrapping the synchronous in a setTimeout allows the DOM to update:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  // do some synchronous computation here
  this.processedAmount++; 
});
```